# Appium, error for create new session signature

Tags: automation, appium, appium-android

cannot create new session for android 11.0 oppo because of the signature problem, i already try to enable "Disable permission Monitoring". its running on another device but not for this os

```
public class testjalan {
    public static AndroidDriver<WebElement> driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {


        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "android");


        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Chrome");

        //capabilities.setCapability("w3c", false);
        capabilities.setCapability("appium:chromeOptions", ImmutableMap.of("w3c", false));
        //capabilities.setCapability("chromedriverExecutable", 


        driver = new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


        driver.get("http://google.com");
        driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("Hello Appium !!!");


        Thread.sleep(5000);


        driver.quit();
```

error message that i getting

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot verify the signature of 'C:\Users\Lenovo IP320\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium Server GUI\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-server\apks\appium-uiautomator2-server-v4.24.0.apk'. Original error: The JAVA_HOME location 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_311' must exist
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'LAPTOP-3S5PCPN8', ip: '192.168.174.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot verify the signature of 'C:\Users\Lenovo IP320\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium Server GUI\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-server\apks\appium-uiautomator2-server-v4.24.0.apk'. Original error: The JAVA_HOME location 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_311' must exist
    at getResponseForW3CError (C:\Users\Lenovo IP320\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium Server GUI\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\errors.js:804:9)
    at asyncHandler (C:\Users\Lenovo IP320\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium Server GUI\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\protocol.js:380:37)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'LAPTOP-3S5PCPN8', ip: '192.168.174.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:216)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:225)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:250)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:41)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.startSession(AppiumDriver.java:363)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:37)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:89)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:99)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:97)
    at test.testjalan.main(testjalan.java:40)
```

what i try to fixing for running in os 11.0 for oppo phone

Answer (score 0):

Please go through your error ,there its clearly telling what's causes your issue

Can you please set your java_path as displayed

> Original error: The JAVA_HOME location 'C:\Program
> Files\Java\jre1.8.0_311' must exist